# shell - How to get every bit from a byte individually?

Tags: shell, loops, binary

I'm writing a little shell script for converting ASCII character to binary and then getting every bit from the resulting byte individually.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
binary=00000000
bit0=0
bit1=0
bit2=0
bit3=0
bit4=0
bit5=0
bit6=0
bit7=0

#main
read -p "Please enter your text: " word

for i in $(seq 1 ${#word})
do

    binary=`echo ${word:i-1:1} | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"'`
    echo $binary

    for n in $(seq 1 ${#binary})
    do

    eval "bit$n=${binary:i-1:1}"

    done

    echo $bit0
    echo $bit1
    echo $bit2
    echo $bit3
    echo $bit4
    echo $bit5
    echo $bit6
    echo $bit7
done
sleep 5
```

For what ever reason this piece here isn't working:

```
for n in $(seq 1 ${#binary})
do

eval "bit$n=${binary:i-1:1}"

done
```

It should assign every bit# variable the correct digit from the binary variable.
Also could you explain this piece of code to me, I don't fully understand it:

```
echo ${word:i-1:1} | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"'
```

Comment: Not sure what you intent can give what you tell you're looking for. Have a look at { typeset a="10"; echo "${a:1:1}" | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"' ; } result. It is "00110000" which is binary representation of 48, taht is ascii code for the '0' at second position of string "01".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, a simple copy&paste fail/error:

eval "bit$n=${binary:***i***-1:1}"
eval "bit$n=${binary:***n***-1:1}"